# Production Server and Local Server get different result

Tags: laravel, git, ubuntu, github

I build API project using Laravel 8, and I put my project on Git. My production server using Ubuntu Apache. I use only 1 database, and it's use on my local and production server.

I have weird problem since yesterday and make me confused. So, I push the latest commit to my Server from Local Server. Everything went well. But when I try to run my API via Postman, the results from my Local and Production server are different.

I checked manually in the files I pushed from local, everything is exactly same.

I try `git status`, everything OK. `git pull` are up to date. Here i attach the screenshoot.
[image]

Since i use laravel, i try to clear cache with `php artisan cache:clear` and it doesn't work.

Here i attach my Postman result:

[image]

As you can see, the result are **different**. I believe, there is no error with my code, It's work well on my Local server.

I try to contact my server provider, but didn't get any solution.

Anyway, this is Header from Prod Server
[image: Header response Prod Server]

I'll appreciate all the answer from this thread. Thank you

Comment: Maybe route cache? Try refreshing all caches with `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: I have try this, but still get same problem

Comment: Could you provide the controller code that is responsible for the response? From your local project and the codebase of the server. To inspect the server code try using "cat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer and comment.

I already solve this problem. The problem pure from my production file and server.

first i try to restart my docker, and then run `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on same branch in local and server? check your git branches in both.

Comment: Yes. It's same branch. I am already solve this by restart my docker and run `php artisan config:clear` . Thank you for your answer